# Cómo hacer que aparezca la fecha actual en el input asociado a un datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

Tengo un input text, el cual lo tengo asociado a un datepicker de UI jquery:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

EL datepicker lo tengo seteado de modo que cuando se piche el input, se muestre por defecto la fecha actual en el calendario que se despliega:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker(
{
  dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  firstDay: 1
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Lo que necesito es saber cómo puedo configurar para que de entrada, en el input que está asociado al datepicker, se muestre la fecha actual, de modo que no sea necesario pinchar el input para que se despliegue el calendario y seleccionar la fecha actual.

Comment: ¿Cuál es el error que le muestra? . al parecer lo que muestra como ejemplo realiza la tarea deseada.

Comment: Dev. Joel, gracias por tu aporte. Te comento que el problema es que cuando se despliega el formulario, en el campo input que está vinculado al datepicker, no se muestra la fecha actual. Se muestra el cuadro de texto input en blanco, luego hay que pincharlo, ahí se despliega el calendario con la fecha actual seleccionada, se pincha o se le da Enter y se cierra el calendario, quedando en el cuadro de texto la fecha actual visible. Lo que quiero es que de entrada, sin hacer nada más, se muestre la fecha actual en el cuadro de texto.  Probé con lo que me indicas, pero no cambia el resultado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intentar con esto.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
 dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: Dev. Joel. Mirando la ejecución de lo que pusiste como respuesta en la página, veo que funciona tal como yo necesito, pero cuando llevo eso a mi desarrollo, no funciona; no sé que es lo que impide que se despliegue de entrada la fecha actual.

Comment: Dev. Joel. Solucionado. Lo que yo tenía puesto originalmente, que era practicamente lo mismo que tu me sugeriste, estaba correcto. El problema del despliegue tenía que ver con otra cosa relacionada con la lógica de funcionamiento del formulario:  Esta fecha se presentaba en un formulario, el cual se invocaba desde el el html, y dentro de la secuencia de acciones que estaba en esta invocación, estaba:

    $('#frmregistrar')[0].reset()

El cual obviamente borraba la fecha que se desplegaba inicialmente.
Fue un error de mi parte no haberme percatado de eso antes. Gracis por tu ayuda.

Comment: Qué bueno que se haya solucionado. Un error le puede ocurrir a cualquiera,  Descuide. Saludos :)