# Problema al integrar FullCalendar y Bootstrap DatePicker: No se actualiza el texto del botón personalizado

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap, fullcalendar, jquery-datepicker

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que utiliza FullCalendar junto con jQuery UI Datepicker. He implementado un botón personalizado (datePickerButton) que abre el datepicker al hacer clic. El objetivo es que, al seleccionar una fecha en el datepicker, el texto de datePickerButton se actualice con la fecha seleccionada.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    themeSystem: 'bootstrap5',
    height: '100%',
    expandRows: true,
    slotMinTime: '07:00',
    slotMaxTime: '20:00',
    customButtons: {
      datePickerButton: {
        text: moment().format('dddd, D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY'),
        themeIcon: 'circle-triangle-s',
        click: function() {
          $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
        }
      }
    },
    slotLabelInterval: {
      minutes: 10
    },
    slotLabelFormat: {
      hour: 'numeric',
      minute: '2-digit',
      omitZeroMinute: false,
      meridiem: 'short',
      hour12: true
    },
    headerToolbar: {
      left: 'prev,next today datePickerButton',
      right: 'timeGridDay,dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,listWeek'
    },
    locale: 'es',
    initialView: 'timeGridDay',
    slotDuration: '00:05:00',
    slotMinTime: '07:00:00',
    slotMaxTime: '24:00:00',
    initialDate: new Date(),
    navLinks: true,
    selectMirror: true,
    select: function(arg) {
      var title = prompt('Event Title:');
      if (title) {
        calendar.addEvent({
          title: title,
          start: arg.start,
          end: arg.end,
          allDay: arg.allDay
        });
      }
      calendar.unselect();
    },
    eventClick: function(arg) {
      if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this event?')) {
        arg.event.remove();
      }
    },
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    nowIndicator: true,
    dayMaxEvents: true,
    dayHeaderFormat: {
      weekday: 'long',
      month: 'long',
      day: 'numeric'
    },
    events: []
  });

  $('#datepicker').hide();

  $('#datePickerButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
  });

  $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    yearRange: 'c-100:c+10',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
      calendar.gotoDate(dateText);

      //AQUI INTENTO CAMBIAR EL TEXTO DEL BOTÓN  PERO NO SE REALIZA

      var selectedDate = moment(dateText).format('dddd, D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY');
      $('.fc-datepicker-button').text(selectedDate);

      $('#datepicker').datepicker('hide');

    },
    beforeShow: function(input, inst) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        inst.dpDiv.css({
          top: 50,
          left: 148
        });
      }, 0);
    }
  });

  calendar.render();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#calendar-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.fc-header-toolbar {
  padding-top: 1em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}

.fc-header-toolbar button {
  background-color: #0d6efd !important;
  color: #fff;
  border: none !important;
}

.fc-header-toolbar button:hover {
  background-color: #004080 !important;
}

.fc-header-toolbar button:focus {
  background-color: #001e3c !important;
  outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css' rel='stylesheet'>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.30.1/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.10/index.global.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fullcalendar/core@6.1.10/locales-all.global.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id='calendar-container'>
  <input type="text" id="datepicker" placeholder="Selecciona una fecha">
  <div id='calendar'></div>
</div>
```

A pesar de mis intentos, no he logrado cambiar el texto del botón datePickerButton con la fecha seleccionada. Actualmente, solo muestra la fecha actual.

¿Cómo puedo lograr que el texto del botón se actualice correctamente con la fecha seleccionada del datepicker?

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia sería apreciada. ¡Gracias!

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Cómo hacer que aparezca la fecha actual en el input asociado a un datepicker](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/35414/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-que-aparezca-la-fecha-actual-en-el-input-asociado-a-un-datepicker)